# How to click a button inside a Popover

Tags: applescript

I am trying to schedule my iTunes downloads using an iCal event. I am able to find the **downloads** button in my *UIElements* but clicking on the downloads button brings a popover which has a **Resume Downloads** button inside. How do I get hold of this button?

Also are there any automator tasks to schedule iTunes and AppStore downloads, I am not to able to find any.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a popover with ui control elements over applescript cause it's ViewController gets deallocated once it closes.

And no there is no time schedule for downloads. If iTunes doesn't offer it you cannot use it.

Comment: I thought there might be a way since I could inspect it via Accessibility Inspector. :(